# How to set an icon/logo next to the title in the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-manifest, android-icons

I have tried:

In onCreate():

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_settings);
```

In manifest:

```
android:logo="@drawable/ic_settings"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
```

And nothing is working. No errors or anything but the icons just don't appear.

Comment: you want to show the icon before or after the title?

Comment: Doesn't matter really, just want to get it to show.@BrunoFerreira

Answer (score 0):

you can **try** this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

**UPDATE** other way:

```
<style name="MyActionBarLogo" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/mainColor500</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo</item>
    </style>
```

And in your main styles:

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarLogo</item>
```

**UPDATE 2** third way you can create a toolbar in activity xml file like that:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Set logo using method `setLogo()` and set **toolbar** as support actionBar like that:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: That also does nothing.

Comment: @Nico I updated my answer with other possible way you can try.

Comment: @Nico I update my question with other way you can try, possible the best soluction